# Get difference of dates in Entity Framework MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I am building an MVC website. I want to show products that are new. So I decided to get the difference between the current date and the date field in the table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

var dateDiff = datetime1 - datetime2;

If you want difference in hours use
var dateDiff = (datetime1 - datetime2).TotalHours;

Note : Make sure that the datetime1/datetime2 are in datetime format not in string format, or else you have convert them to datetime and then get the difference.